# What does Islam say about birth of living being?

Tags: quran, creation, soul, world

What does Islam say about birth of living being? I've read that according to Quran, God(Allah) is creator, destroyer, judge,..etc. So, as we know that world is made of two things 1.sentient/living(सजीव) and 2. non-sentient/non-living/(निर्जीव). Now non-living things are made once but what about living beings?

If Jivas are only made once then how world has continue new Jivas? I am not sure about whether Islam believes in re-birth of Jivas. So, I want to understand the life-cycle of Jivas. Also I'm interested for the cause of world and Jivas according to Islam.

Note that I'm new to learn about Islam and As far as I know Quran is considered as the final truth from Allah. So, I prefer the information/knowledge from Quran. (Quote the verses from Quran related to this question).

<sup>If there are a specific terms for world, jivas, re-birth etc according to Islam, then tell me to use it.</sup>

Comment: somewhat related [How is the concept of Reincarnation treated in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/772/how-is-the-concept-of-reincarnation-treated-in-islam)

Comment: Muslims would probably better understand "Jiva" as *nafs* (نَفْس) or soul.

Comment: do you mean that if there is no reincarnation then how does the world have new humans?

Comment: @goldPseudo, 'jiva' a hindi term means a 'living being with soul', so it's nearest interpretation would be just soul or as complete (above in quotes)

Comment: also I think the OP want's to say if souls (as in 'ro:h') were created just once then how come this world continues to get new souls